# How to combine two dictionaries from two imbalance list in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

The objective is to get a single `dictionary` resulting from the merging of two `dictionaries` that each come from different `list`.

For a balance list (i.e., if the list have same `len`), this can be achieved simply by using `zip`:

```
first_list = [{'val': 1, 'item': 'item1'}, {'val': 2, 'item': 'item2'}, {'val': 3, 'item': 'item3'}]
sec_list = [{'idx': 1, 'other': '1'}, {'idx': 2, 'other': '2'}, {'idx': 3, 'other': '3'}]

new_result=[]
for first_list_x,sec_list_x in zip(first_list,sec_list):
    new_result.append({**first_list_x, **sec_list_x})
```

and produced

```
new_result = [{'val': 1,'item': 'item1', 'idx': 1, 'other': '1'}, \
                 {'val': 2,'item': 'item2', 'idx': 2, 'other': '2'}, \
                 {'val': 3,'item': 'item3', 'idx': 3, 'other': '3'}]
```

Note that, the order is matter, such that, `val:1` will stay under the same hood with `idx:1`.

However, thing get trickier if the two list are not of the same length, as shown below:

```
first_list = [{'val': 1, 'item': 'item1'}, {'val': 2, 'item': 'item2'}, {'val': 3, 'item': 'item3'}]
sec_list = [{'idx': 1, 'other': '1'}, {'idx': 2, 'other': '2'}]

new_result=[]
for first_list_x,sec_list_x in zip(first_list,sec_list):
    new_result.append({**first_list_x, **sec_list_x})
```

will produced

```
new_result=[{'val': 1, 'item': 'item1', 'idx': 1, 'other': '1'},
             {'val': 2, 'item': 'item2', 'idx': 2, 'other': '2'}]
```

While the code produced what it supposed to output, but my desire is to have the `{'val': 3, 'item': 'item3'}` in the new dict. Such that, the expected output should be

```
new_result = [{'val': 1,'item': 'item1', 'idx': 1, 'other': '1'}, \
                 {'val': 2,'item': 'item2', 'idx': 2, 'other': '2'}, \
                 {'val': 3,'item': 'item3'}]
```

May I know how to achieved the above objective for an imbalance list. Also, appreciate if there is other recommendation that much more faster than the usage of `zip` and `{**x, **y}`.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip_longest` from `itertools` instead of `zip`. And using `zip` or `zip_longest`  along with `{**x, **y}` would probably be the fastest

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> 
>>> first_list = [{'val': 1, 'item': 'item1'}, {'val': 2, 'item': 'item2'}, {'val': 3, 'item': 'item3'}]
>>> sec_list = [{'idx': 1, 'other': '1'}, {'idx': 2, 'other': '2'}]
>>> 
>>> [dict(**d1, **d2) for  d1,d2 in zip_longest(first_list,sec_list, fillvalue={})]
[{'val': 1, 'item': 'item1', 'idx': 1, 'other': '1'}, 
 {'val': 2, 'item': 'item2', 'idx': 2, 'other': '2'},
 {'val': 3, 'item': 'item3'}]
```